# Error shows preventing parallelization when I compiled the C++ code with openacc

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing, openacc

When I compiled the code with openacc ,I got the warning information:

```
$  pgc++ -o buffer1.out -acc -gpu=managed -Minfo=accel buffer.cpp
main:
    137, Generating enter data copyin(mat1)
         Generating NVIDIA GPU code
        143, #pragma acc loop seq collapse(2)
        145,   collapsed */
    137, Generating default present(mat1)
    143, Complex loop carried dependence of  prevents parallelization
    145, Complex loop carried dependence of  prevents parallelization
    148, Reference argument passing prevents parallelization: j
         Reference argument passing prevents parallelization: i
    150, Accelerator restriction: induction variable live-out from loop: j
    153, Accelerator restriction: induction variable live-out from loop: i
    161, Generating update self(mat1)
         Generating exit data delete(mat1)
Array2D<int>::operator ()(const int &, const int &):
     23, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating NVIDIA GPU code
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include<queue>
#include<openacc.h>
using namespace std;

template<class T1>
class Array2D{

public:
        int arows=0;
        int acols=0;
        T1**  __restrict matImg;
Array2D(int rows,int cols,T1 defaultVal):arows(rows),acols(cols){

matImg=new T1*[rows];
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
   matImg[i]=new T1[cols];
   memset(matImg[i],defaultVal,sizeof(T1)*cols);
   }
}

T1 &operator()(const int& m, const int& n){

 return matImg[m][n];


 }


T1 * __restrict operator()(const int&k){

 return matImg[k];

}


~Array2D(){

for(int i=0;i<arows;i++){
    delete[] matImg[i];
   }
   delete [] matImg;

 }

};
int main(){

int rows=6;
int cols=10;
Array2D<int> mat1=Array2D<int>(rows,cols,0);//Array2D<int>(2,3);



#pragma acc enter data copyin(mat1[0:rows][0:cols])
#pragma acc parallel loop collapse(2) default(present)
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){

 for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
  // cout<<"mat1("<<i<<","<<j<<") :"<<mat1(i,j)<<endl;

   mat1(i,j)+=2;

 }


}



#pragma acc update self(mat1)
#pragma acc exit data delete(mat1)

cout<<"=============================="<<endl;


for(int i=0;i<mat1.arows;i++){

 for(int j=0;j<mat1.acols;j++){
   cout<<"mat1("<<i<<","<<j<<") :"<<mat1(i,j)<<endl;



  }


  }
}
```

> Array2D is a class for creating 2D array object by allocating heap.
>
> It says the array prevents the parallel in GPU code. Image is a Mat
> data type from openCV. May I know why the warning says there is a
> dependency?
>
> Could somebody provide any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct code that matches the compiler feedback?  There's no "antimat" variable, the "row" and "col" variables are "int" not pointers, and it doesn't appear that "i" and "j" are not being passed by reference.  Granted, the example code is incomplete so I can't compile it, so there may be some missing information.  Can you please post a complete stand-alone minimal reproducing example?

Comment: Hello Mat, sorry for the confusion. I updated the code for simplification.Please take a look and kindly provide hint.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the index variables by value instead of by reference.  By passing them by reference, the compiler must assume that the address is taken by a global pointer thus creating a dependency.

To fix:

```
T1 &operator()(int m, int n){
 return matImg[m][n];
}
```

While the loop will now be successfully parallelized, you'll get a runtime error since "mat1" isn't an 2D array, but rather a class with a 2D array data member.  Instead you need to do a deep copy of "mat1" to the device.

Full fix:

```
% cat test.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include<queue>
#include<openacc.h>
using namespace std;

template<class T1>
class Array2D{

public:
        int arows=0;
        int acols=0;
        T1**  __restrict matImg;
Array2D(int rows,int cols,T1 defaultVal):arows(rows),acols(cols){

matImg=new T1*[rows];
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
   matImg[i]=new T1[cols];
   memset(matImg[i],defaultVal,sizeof(T1)*cols);
   }
}


T1 &operator()(int m, int n){
 return matImg[m][n];
}


T1 * __restrict operator()(const int&k){

 return matImg[k];

}


~Array2D(){

for(int i=0;i<arows;i++){
    delete[] matImg[i];
   }
   delete [] matImg;

 }

};
int main(){

int rows=6;
int cols=10;
Array2D<int> mat1=Array2D<int>(rows,cols,0);//Array2D<int>(2,3);


#pragma acc enter data copyin(mat1, mat1.matImg[0:rows][0:cols])
#pragma acc parallel loop collapse(2) default(present)
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
 for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
  // cout<<"mat1("<<i<<","<<j<<") :"<<mat1(i,j)<<endl;
   mat1(i,j)+=2;
 }


}
#pragma acc update self(mat1.matImg[0:rows][0:cols])
#pragma acc exit data delete(mat1.matImg,mat1)

cout<<"=============================="<<endl;


for(int i=0;i<mat1.arows;i++){

 for(int j=0;j<mat1.acols;j++){
   cout<<"mat1("<<i<<","<<j<<") :"<<mat1(i,j)<<endl;



  }


  }
}

% nvc++ test.cpp -acc -Minfo=accel -O2 -V22.11 ; a.out
main:
     50, Generating enter data copyin(mat1,mat1.matImg[:rows][:cols])
         Generating NVIDIA GPU code
         55, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(64) collapse(2) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
         56,   /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x collapsed */
     50, Generating default present(mat1.matImg[:6],mat1)
     66, Generating update self(mat1.matImg[:rows][:cols])
         Generating exit data delete(mat1.matImg[:1][:1],mat1)
Array2D<int>::operator ()(int, int):
     24, Generating implicit acc routine seq
         Generating acc routine seq
         Generating NVIDIA GPU code
==============================
mat1(0,0) :2
mat1(0,1) :2
mat1(0,2) :2
mat1(0,3) :2
mat1(0,4) :2
mat1(0,5) :2
mat1(0,6) :2
mat1(0,7) :2
... cut ...
mat1(5,7) :2
mat1(5,8) :2
mat1(5,9) :2
```

Comment: Hello Mat,thank you very much. I understand the reason why the code can not run successfully.  One more question,if I want to use cout<< in the region of #pragma acc.How could I invoke the cout in parallel region?for example:                                                                          
 #pragma acc enter data copyin(mat1, mat1.matImg[0:rows][0:cols])
#pragma acc parallel loop collapse(2) default(present)
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
 for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
   cout<<"mat1("<<i<<","<<j<<") :"<<mat1(i,j)<<endl;

 }


}

Comment: I/O is limited from the device and "cout" isn't supported as of yet.  Instead use a C-style "printf" statement.